# Folding multiple (discrete) operations into one (continuous) operation

Tags: c, math, optimization, discrete-mathematics

For a simple example, suppose we're checking whether a `char c` is alphanumeric:

```
if (48 <= c && c <= 57 ||
    65 <= c && c <= 90 ||
    97 <= c && c <= 122)
{
    // ...
}
```

6 operations to confirm that it *is*.

But, doesn't there exist a continuous function *f(c)* such that *f(c) > 0* for the alphanumeric byte values, and *< 0* for the rest? I think there *is* at least one: a polynomial of degree 12, that "fits" 12 points, weaving up and down the x-axis; but maybe there exists a function of smaller degrees, too, or even non-polynomials. Such a formula would "simplify" the operations to:

```
if (f(c) > 0)
{
    // ...
}
```

**Is there a term of art for this?** (The word "folding" comes to mind, but it doesn't yield any relevant search results—only Haskell's concept of folding.) It seems that as long as we can map the codomain of a set of operations to a codomain of sufficiently finer granularity, we can obtain such a "fold". My question, then, is: **can "folding" save time?** Or is there some principle of conservation that forces the cost of computing a "fold" to match (or even exceed) the cost of computing the original, "crude" operations.

Comment: This seems like an interesting theoretical question, but compared with alternatives like the code above (which should be *extremely* fast), or using a lookup table, are you sure that a polynomial would even be faster?

Comment: @templatetypedef - No, of course, in the above example, a lookup table would be much faster; but I'm starting with a simple case to extend to a more general case where there may be infinite (but countable) points in the codomain (and thus not enumerable in a lookup table).

Comment: This is *wrong*. You should be using character constants such as `'0'`, `'9'`, `'A'`, `'Z'`, `'a'` and `'z'` for the purpose of internal documentation. Do you want us to read your code, or not? There are *more than six operations* occuring there. Count them from left to right, by counting the operators from left to right: `<=` `&&` `<=` `||` `<=` `&&` `<=` `||` `<=` `&&` `<=`. C does not guarantee that ASCII will be used. EBCDIC might be used, instead, in which case this code *will fail miserably*! Don't prematurely optimise, or code like this! Just use `isupper`, `islower` and `isdigit`.

Comment: Furthermore, the C language doesn't have speed. That's an attribute introduced by implementations. There are fast C implementations and slow C implementations. Who's to say a lookup table would be faster? Perhaps `CHAR_BIT == 16`, in which case `unsigned char lookup_table[UCHAR_MAX];` occupies 65536 bytes of memory and would be painfully cache-unfriendly! Let your compiler do these optimisations for you. It probably has a better idea of what will be effective. Otherwise, consider profiling a program that solves an actual problem to determine whether or not this is a significant bottleneck.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour - Ironically, I fear you've prematurely optimized your comments ;-) I appreciate, respect, and completely agree with what you're saying, but I am not actually asking about alphanumericness, C (I only tagged it so because my example was in C), caching, compiler optimization, or profiling. My example was meant to elucidate a theoretical question I had. Perhaps I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: I still think those comments raise some good points regarding your code, and some relevant points: If a compiler generates code to *fold* your example code, then this answers one of your questions.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour - Ah, that's a good point---I'm sure the compiler has been built to do such "folding." In my case, there's a cryptographic algorithm I'd been staring at for a while, and I realized that if such "folding" were possible, I could possibly find a general method for optimizing a "folded" decrypting algorithm. I'm obviously lacking too much fundamental knowledge to approach this problem; but that's why I sought keywords for this kind of optimization. Thanks for commenting though! All ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but you could change order of comparisons to improve short-circuiting.

Comment: \@hyde - Prepare to get schooled by @undefinedbehaviour ;-)

Comment: @acheong87 Does it seem like this might be an area covered by common subexpression elimination?

Comment: Another optimization to more quickly prune out negative cases, applicable *sometimes*, would be to first use a bit mask test to rule out values with wrong bits set/unset: `if (((c & bitmask) == masked_value) && ...) {` (obviously bitmask and masked_value need to be pre-calced for this to optimize anything, be it run time or compile time pre-calc).

Comment: @hyde Introducing code to handle irrelevant cases doesn't sound like a significant optimisation to me. Perhaps you might wish to revise [the list of optimisations performed by gcc-4.8.0](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)...

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour - Er, I couldn't say. To be honest, my approaches to solving this cryptographic problem are all shots in the dark. I don't know what I'm doing. I just noticed that there were chains of `xor` operations that left a sin-wave like "imprint" at a certain chain of crypting, and that led to continuous-function-based ideas. But hm, the concept of common subexpression elimination does lead to different insights about the problem.

Comment: @acheong87 `-fcompare-elim` seems to describe this: *... identify arithmetic instructions that compute processor flags similar to a comparison operation based on that arithmetic. If possible, eliminate the explicit comparison operation.*

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour I assume your comment about "irrelevant cases" refers to bitmask comparison. Well, it depends on the case if it is irrelevant. Suitable set of ranges would be covered by the right bitmask comparison alone, so existence of such a way bears mentioning. And I doubt gcc can do it as a general reliable optimization (thought it would be cool if it actually can).

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour I do agree 100%, that you should nearly always leave all this for compiler, and only consider micro-optimization after profiling and perhaps looking at compiler assembly output.

Comment: @hyde: The compiler often can't do this kind of 'optimization' because it relies on specialized knowledge about the range of the input. For instance, evaluating the polynomial could easily overflow unless you have bounds on the input value.

Comment: @R. Unless it has specialised knowledge about the range of the input... Consider profile-guided optimisation.

Comment: @hyde ... and even then, *you* probably can't produce that optimisation as quickly as a version of your compiler modified to produce the optimisation automatically could, across so many projects across the planet... Don't apply micro-optimisations to your project. Apply them to the compiler, or tell someone who can about your idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The polynomial intersects the x-axis 6 times, i.e. it has 6 real roots, so a degree-6 polynomial is enough.

> ```
> f(c) = -(c-48)*(c-57)*(c-65)*(c-90)*(c-97)*(c-122)
> ```
>
> [image]

This of course will *waste* time, doing 5 multiplications is much slower than 5 logical operations. Furthermore, `&&` and `||` are short-circuiting so often you don't need to do all of them.

Comment: Wow, thanks for finding the polynomial! Interesting. I didn't think intersection at the zeroes would be enough (the direction wouldn't be determined), but I was definitely wrong about 12! But okay, clearly polynomials only increase complexity---yet they are the trivial solutions---I wish I knew the general term for this so that I could look into what methods there exist for more clever "folding" (e.g. non-polynomials).

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you came up with this polynomial and knew that it would oscillate up and down between the roots, rather than (say, touching 0 at a root, then reflecting back into the same half?)

Comment: It's not a matter of 5 muls vs 5 logical operators. It's a matter of 5 muls and 1 branch versus multiple branches. If most characters you see are alphanumeric, but fall in different ranges (upper/lower/numeric), the version with 5 muls might still perform better due to superior branch prediction results.

Comment: It doesn't seem like I'll be getting any answers reaching beyond the specifics of my example; this did complete the demonstration of my example (namely, showing the ineffectiveness of polynomials), so I'm accepting it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: It is actually a wonderful and eye opening answer.  It solves a problem in a way I had never thought of - a way that may result in better solutions to similiar problems in the future for me.  The form of the answer above is elegant as well - showing exactly how it works.  I am very impressed.

Comment: BTW, I could think of cases where 5 muls could be done faster than 5 compares in SIMD type situations so don't dismiss it to easily.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Only a repeated root (something like (c - 10)^2) will touch 0 and reflect back. I think there's a mathematical theory for this.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: Indeed, with SIMD you could parallelize it somewhat, but not entirely, since the operands are dependent. SIMD makes less sense for the polynomial solution and more for my approach (one vector subtract and one vector comparison, both against constant vectors).

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: SIMD can support logical operations e.g. SSE's ANDPS, ORPS. There's no need to do multiplication.

Comment: Ok, may not that example, but my initial assertion that having multiple ways of solving the same problem is valid.  You never know what is "fast" on various machines.

Answer (score 4):

In your particular case, the optimal form is:

```
unsigned u = c;
if (u-48<10 || (u|32)-97<26)
```

Granted this does not solve the problem the way you were looking to, but the same concepts (i.e. (1) turning two comparisons against a range into one unsigned subtraction and comparison, and (2) using bitwise-or to combine multiple range checks whose lengths are the same and for which the alignments match like this) can often be generalized to other situations.

Answer (score 2):

Is there some reason that the function `isalnum()` doesn't suffice for your needs? Don't forget to `#include <ctype.h>`.

Comment: This is a great comment... but I'm not sure if it's a great answer. I like it, anyway. +1.

Comment: No, to the theoretical math question being asked, it's a terrible answer. But then, this is a *programmers* forum.

Comment: Ah, my actual problem isn't related to alphanumericness. But good point; thanks. I just picked a bad example.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson Do you think this question should be closed?

Comment: Perhaps. I think it belongs on a different forum, but I couldn't say which.

Comment: `isalnum` operates based on the current locale, not a fixed set of values, so it's almost always the wrong answer unless your data is "text in the current locale". In particular it's usually wrong for "text" files oriented at machine interpretation.